# PHP - Convert a Single Array into a Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm newbie in PHP.

I need send data for API purpose.

I have array `print_r($detail)` like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => item1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [price] => 300
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 1
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => item2
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [price] => 400
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 2
        )
)
```

And I want convert it to multidimensional before sending to another process, like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => item1
            [price] => 300
            [quantity] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => item2
            [price] => 400
            [quantity] => 2
        )
)
```

How it is possible?

Comment: Make it correctly at the source, rather than making it like it is now and then later trying to write more code to fix it. How do you generate this array?

Comment: If you've no control over the source, you'll need to manually iterate of your initial array, every time you "collect" all three components of a single item, you can push them into you. This feels error prone however.

Comment: I got the first array from other server, I cant in to the source

Comment: Checkout me at [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274060/php-convert-a-single-array-into-a-multidimensional-array/36274929#36274929)

Answer (score 2):

You can split your `$details` array into multiple chunks. I've written the following function which accepts a custom chunk size (note `count($initialArray) % $chunkSize === 0` must be true):

```
function transformArray(array $initialArray, $chunkSize = 3) {
    if (count($initialArray) % $chunkSize != 0) {
        throw new \Exception('The length of $initialArray must be divisible by ' . $chunkSize);
    }

    $chunks = array_chunk($initialArray, 3);
    $result = [];

    foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
        $newItem = [];

        foreach ($chunk as $item) {
            $newItem[array_keys($item)[0]] = reset($item);
        }

        $result[] = $newItem;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Given your details array, calling `transformArray($details)` will result in:

[image]

The customizable chunk size allows you to add more data to your source array:

```
$details = [
    ['id' => 'item1'],
    ['price' => 300],
    ['quantity' => 1],
    ['anotherProp' => 'some value'],
    ['id' => 'item2'],
    ['price' => 400],
    ['quantity' => 2],
    ['anotherProp' => 'another value'],
];
```

The function call is now `transformArray($details, 4);`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This version may be with the same result of @PHPglue answer. But this takes only one `foreach`. I think this is faster, more efficient way as stated here by one of the Top SO Users.

[image]

Try to look if you want it.

[**Live Demo**](http://ideone.com/QGCS5h)

```
<?php

function explodeArray($arr)
{
    $newArr = array();
    foreach($arr as $row)
    {
        $key = array_keys($row)[0];
        $curArr = count($newArr) > 0 ? $newArr[count($newArr)-1] : array();
        if( array_key_exists($key, $curArr) )
        {
            array_push($newArr, array($key=>$row[$key]) );
        }
        else
        {
            $index = count($newArr) > 0 ? count($newArr) - 1 : 0 ;
            $newArr[$index][$key] = $row[$key];
        }
    }
    return $newArr;
}
```

Different Arrays for testing.

```
$detail = array(
        array('id'=>'item1'),
        array('price'=>300),
        array('quantity'=>1),
        array('id'=>'item2'),
        array('price'=>400),
        array('quantity'=>2)
    );

var_dump( explodeArray($detail) );

$detail_match = array(
        array('id'=>'item1'),
        array('price'=>300),
        array('quantity'=>1),
        array('newkey'=>'sample'),
        array('id'=>'item2'),
        array('price'=>400),
        array('quantity'=>2),
        array('newkey'=>'sample')
    );

var_dump( explodeArray($detail_match) ); // Works with any size of keys.

$detail_diff_key = array(
        array('id'=>'item1'),
        array('price'=>300),
        array('quantity'=>1),
        array('diff1'=>'sample1'),
        array('id'=>'item2'),
        array('price'=>400),
        array('quantity'=>2),
        array('diff2'=>'sample2')
    );

var_dump( explodeArray($detail_diff_key) ); // Works with any size of keys and different keys.

$detail_unmatch = array(
        array('id'=>'item1'),
        array('price'=>300),
        array('quantity'=>1),
        array('unmatchnum'=>'sample1'),
        array('id'=>'item2'),
        array('price'=>400),
        array('quantity'=>2)
    );

var_dump( explodeArray($detail_unmatch) );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this little block of code work for you.

**Use:**

```
$detail = array(
    "0" => array("id" => "item1"),
    "1" => array("price" => "300"),
    "2" => array("quantity" => "1"),
    "3" => array("id" => "item2"),
    "4" => array("price" => "400"),
    "5" => array("quantity" => "2"),
    "6" => array("id" => "item3"),
    "7" => array("price" => "500"),
    "8" => array("quantity" => "3")
);

$i = 0;
$j = 0;
$multi_details = array();
while($j < count($detail)){
    $multi_details[$i][id] = $detail[$j++][id];
    $multi_details[$i][price] = $detail[$j++][price];
    $multi_details[$i][quantity] =  $detail[$j++][quantity];
    $i++;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($multi_details);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => item1
            [price] => 300
            [quantity] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => item2
            [price] => 400
            [quantity] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => item3
            [price] => 500
            [quantity] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: I got an error: Illegal string offset

Comment: let me double check.

Comment: Its fine, Check now.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it

```
$newArray = array();
$newRow = array();
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $key = array_keys($row)[0];
    $value = array_values($row)[0];
    if ($key == 'id') {
        $newArray[] = $newRow;
    }
    $newRow[$key] = $value;
}
$newArray[] = $newRow;
```

Comment: Thanks, but how implement with multiple $key ?

Comment: @Vinsens   what do you mean "multiple $key"?

Answer (score 0):

This version looks for repeat keys then creates a new Array whenever they are the same so you could have some different data. Hope it helps.

```
function customMulti($customArray){
  $a = array(); $n = -1; $d;
  foreach($customArray as $i => $c){
    foreach($c as $k => $v){
      if(!isset($d)){
        $d = $k;
      }
      if($k === $d){
        $a[++$n] = array();
      }
      $a[$n][$k] = $v;
    }
  }
  return $a;
}
$wow = customMulti(array(array('id'=>'item1'),array('price'=>300),array('quantity'=>1),array('id'=>'item2'),array('price'=>400),array('quantity'=>2)));
print_r($wow);
```